# Deleting the columns from the typeorm entities

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I am pretty new to the NestJS/typeorm system. So while working, I created an `Episode` entity and added some fields. Then I updated the entity to remove and update some fields. But after running the application, it still has the deleted columns ( checked it on pgAdmin ). The migrations are not updated to delete the columns. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Do you have `synchronize:true` set in your TypeORM configuration?

Comment: Yes. It adds new columns added to the entity, but does not remove the deleted ones.

Comment: TypeORM has a really bad issue with caching columns and not deleting them. Usual remedy is `rm -rf dist` (or the windows equivalent) and start the server again

Comment: Thank You very much. It worked.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

TypeORM kept the column definitions in a cache somehow and did not allow them to be deleted. This can be fixed by running `rm -rf dist` (or the Windows equivalent) and then rebuilding the project

Comment: I'll just comment here that his works on NestJS, in case someone searches for it.